# How do I stop all JavaScript executing from within an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
Interface.init = function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Validate",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Valid) {
                // All good, continue executing JS code
            }
            else {
                // Display error messsage, attempt to stop executing JS code...
                return false;
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            // Display error message, attempt to stop executing JS code...
            return false;
        }
    });

    // More JavaScript functions used to load content, etc...
}
```

The index page calls `Interface.init()` on load:

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Interface.init();
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

The `ajax` function is used to check if the device loading the page is valid. It is run `synchronously` so the page waits for the validation to complete before continuing. If the validation is successful, the `ajax` function is exited and the rest of the JavaScript code continues to execute. If the validation fails (or there is an error during the validation), I don't want any of the remaining JavaScript code to be executed.

I'm currently using `return false`, but I've also tried just `return` and throwing an error such as `throw new Error("Validation failed")` (as suggested by numerous other questions).

All these seem to do is exit the `ajax` function and all remaining JavaScript on the page continues to execute. Outside of the `ajax` function, these methods work as expected to stop the remaining code from executing, but I was hoping for this to be done from within the `ajax` function. Is this at all possible?

Comment: _"the page waits for the validation to complete before continuing. If the validation is successful, the ajax function is exited and the rest of the JavaScript code continues to execute. If the validation fails (or there is an error during the validation), I want ALL JavaScript on the page to stop executing."_ Stopping `js` depends on response from`$.ajax()` ?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi - The question you marked this a duplicate of, does not come even close to what I am asking here.

Comment: @sfinks, please explain exactly what you're asking here, then. *I want* ***ALL*** *JavaScript on the page to stop executing* looks pretty clear to me.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Have you read the answers to that question? Anyway, if the validation fails or an error occurs, nothing more should be done with the page, ie. no more code to be executed, the page basically becomes dead.

Comment: @sfinks, *sigh*, yes, I have read the answers under the duplicate, and they basically say it's not possible to stop ***ALL*** the scripts in a page, which is what you're asking (in the end of the paragraph under your second code snippet, with emphasis and all). If that's not what you're asking, then **please edit your question to make it clearer**. Thank you.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - I've updated the question to say "I don't want any of the remaining JavaScript code to be executed", hopefully that makes it a little clearer for you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an outside variable before the function and use it after it, e.g:

```
Interface.init = function()
{
    var error = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Validate",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Valid) {
                // All good, continue executing JS code
            }
            else {
                error = true;
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            error = true;
        }
    });

    if (error) return;
    // More JavaScript functions used to load content, etc...
}
```

---

But in fact, I recommend to not use the `async=false`, and instead of that, you could wrap the rest of your code in a function, and call it inside the callback, e.g:

```
Interface.init = function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Validate",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Valid) {
                // All good, continue executing JS code
                loadAll();
            }
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });

    function loadAll() {
        // More JavaScript functions used to load content, etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as it would probably work, using `async false` isn't probably the smartest thing to do. Didn't downvote thought.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I agree with you, but that was not the OP's question. He's already using `async=false` and he wanted to know how to proceed.

Comment: Questioner wants ***ALL*** *JavaScript on the page to stop executing* (emphasis theirs). Your solution does not achieve that.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix How would you approach this without using `async false`? (I didn't downvote either..)

Comment: @sfinks_29 updated my answer showing an example with an approach without using `async=false`

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi although he said "*I want ALL JavaScript on the page to stop executing*", it's completely clear for me that his goal is to not execute all the code he has below the AJAX call.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi disabling javascript if an error happens isn't probably what the OP's asking. My guess is that it wan't it to stop initing if an error happens or if validation is failing. Stopping **ALL** javascript is probably not what OPs want because then, it won't be possible to recover from an error and could make the webpage useless.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix exactly :)

Comment: @Buzinas, is it that clear to you? It's not to me. However, if you have the questioner explicitly say that in their question, the duplicate will indeed not stand.

Comment: @sfinks_29 was my answer useful for you?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That duplicate question has absolutely no link whatsoever to this question.

Comment: @Buzinas Yes I think that is going to work in my situation.

Comment: @sfinks_29 ok, then! if it doesn't work, let me know and I try to help you. Have a good one :)

Comment: @Loïc, come on. Duplicate question: *Is there a way to stop all javascript on the page?* This question: *I want* ***ALL*** *JavaScript on the page to stop executing.* And you say there is absolutely no "link" between the two?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi This was the accepted answer: "Basing off of Matchu's suggestion. You could get a copy of Fiddler, modify the page locally to suit your needs, have Chrome proxy through Fiddler. Then you can tell fiddler that when it sees a request for the page of interest, serve the local file instead.

I've done something like this before to debug some Javascript compiled into a .NET assembly, so I wouldn't have to recompile for every script change, just refresh the page.".... NOT EVEN CLOSE

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi the thing is: his question has dozens of lines, and you are focusing on one single line that he didn't mean what you're interpreting - and everyone else saw that, and the OP already said that my answer was useful for him, but you're being kindda headstrong here.